# S3 web hosting endpoint produce "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: amazon-s3, web-hosting

I am trying to host a static web page on AWS S3 but get "This site can’t be reached" when trying to reach my endpoint: http://iekdosha-test1.com.s3-website-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/

- This is my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::iekdosha-test1.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- The "Block public access" all set to "Off" both in bucket and in account settings
- "Static website hosting" is enabled with my index.html page (test file with simple message)
- My bucket name is iekdosha-test1.com
- An orange "Public" tag appears under "permissions" in bucket page and on all buckets page i have the same orange "Public" tag on my bucket's "Access" column.
- I have followed this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html?refid=gs_card#root-domain-walkthrough-s3-tasks) and got stuck on step 2.8 (testing the endpoint)

What could possibly be the issue?

Comment: Use this URL: http://iekdosha-test1.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eu-central-1 region does not use the old style `${bucket}.s3-website-${region}.amazonaws.com` endoint convention for web site hosting endpoints.  You need a dot `.` rather than a dash `-` after the word `website` in URLs for this region -- `${bucket}.s3-website.${region}.amazonaws.com`.

This newer style actually works in any region, even though the [Regions and Endpoints documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) still shows the old style endpoints for older regions.